# Independent events?

Tags: probability

Say we toss a coin that is fair twice we have sample space $:[HH,TH,HT,TT]$. Let's say $A$ is the event with the first throw a head. $A=[HH,HT]$. $B$ is the event with the second throw  is a head. $B=[HH,TH]$. $C$ is the event with the first throw a tail. $C=[TH,TT]$. Show that $A$ and $B$ are independent but $A$ and $C$ are not.

I know I need to show $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ or $P(A|B)=P(A)$ for the first part and simply show these equalities to be false for the second part but  I'm not sure how, any help?

Comment: We have $\Pr(A\cap C)=0$, but $\Pr(A)=\Pr(C)=1/2$.

Comment: Yeah figured it out. TY

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the probabilities explicitly. Your sample space has only four elements and each has equal probability. So $P(A)=P([HH,HT])=\frac12$, for instance. What is $A\cap B$? Can you calculate $P(B),P(C),P(A\cap B)$ and $P(A\cap C)$?

Comment: Got it guys thanks.